# PYTHON - Ctypes : OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xFFFFFFFFFA1C001B

Tags: python, ctypes, dllimport, memory-mapped-files

Here is a code for writing values to memory using memory mapping. When I try to run the code, I get the error 
   ***"File "MMF.py", line 26, in 
    memcpy(pBuf, szMsg, len(szMsg)) 
    OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xFFFFFFFFFA1C001B"***

```
import msvcrt, mmap
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = 0x04
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = 0xFFFFFFFF
SHMEMSIZE = 256
PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04
szName = ctypes.c_wchar_p("MyFileMappingObject")
szMsg = "Message from Python(ctypes) process"

hMapObject = windll.kernel32.CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,None, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SHMEMSIZE, szName)
print("Handle:",hMapObject)
if (hMapObject == 0):
    print("Could not open file mapping object")
    raise WinError()

pBuf = windll.kernel32.MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0, 0, SHMEMSIZE)
print("Buffer Starting Addr:",pBuf)
if (pBuf == 0):
    print("Could not map view of file")
    raise WinError()
else:
    print(len(szMsg))
    memcpy = cdll.msvcrt.memcpy
    memcpy(pBuf, szMsg, len(szMsg))

shmem = mmap.mmap(0, 256, "MyFileMappingObject_ctypes", mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
shmem.write("Message Python process")

msvcrt.getch()

windll.kernel32.UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf)
windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hMapObject)
shmem.close()
```

Comment: You will need to specify argtypes and restype on these imports otherwise they will default to 32 bit integer. Not what you want.

Comment: + you don't mix native functions with *Python* objects or viceversa. And some constants are incorrectly used/defined.

Comment: I tried initializing argtypes and still the result is same

Comment: @prabakars Then maybe you made a mistake in the ”declarations”. We can't tell until we see what you've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before anything, here's (almost) everything that you need: [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). *ctypes.wintypes* is not explained, but you can see its exports by running `dir(ctypes.wintypes)` in the *Python* console. Note that all these types are simple *CTypes* types, I use them just for convention / consistency / readability's sake.

Your updated code (*code00.py*):

```py
import sys
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as wt
import mmap
import msvcrt


def main(*argv):
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = 0x000F001F
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
    SHMEMSIZE = 0x100
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04

    kernel32_dll = ct.windll.kernel32
    msvcrt_dll = ct.cdll.msvcrt  # To be avoided

    CreateFileMapping = kernel32_dll.CreateFileMappingW
    CreateFileMapping.argtypes = (wt.HANDLE, wt.LPVOID, wt.DWORD, wt.DWORD, wt.DWORD, wt.LPCWSTR)
    CreateFileMapping.restype = wt.HANDLE

    MapViewOfFile = kernel32_dll.MapViewOfFile
    MapViewOfFile.argtypes = (wt.HANDLE, wt.DWORD, wt.DWORD, wt.DWORD, ct.c_ulonglong)
    MapViewOfFile.restype = wt.LPVOID

    memcpy = msvcrt_dll.memcpy
    memcpy.argtypes = (ct.c_void_p, ct.c_void_p, ct.c_size_t)
    memcpy.restype = wt.LPVOID

    RtlCopyMemory = kernel32_dll.RtlCopyMemory
    RtlCopyMemory.argtypes = (wt.LPVOID, wt.LPCVOID, ct.c_ulonglong)

    UnmapViewOfFile = kernel32_dll.UnmapViewOfFile
    UnmapViewOfFile.argtypes = (wt.LPCVOID,)
    UnmapViewOfFile.restype = wt.BOOL

    CloseHandle = kernel32_dll.CloseHandle
    CloseHandle.argtypes = (wt.HANDLE,)
    CloseHandle.restype = wt.BOOL

    GetLastError = kernel32_dll.GetLastError

    file_mapping_name_ptr = ct.c_wchar_p("MyFileMappingObject")
    msg = "Message from Python(ctypes) process"
    msg_ptr = ct.c_wchar_p(msg)

    mapping_handle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SHMEMSIZE, file_mapping_name_ptr)

    print("Mapping object handle: 0x{:016X}".format(mapping_handle))
    if not mapping_handle:
        print("Could not open file mapping object: {:d}".format(GetLastError()))
        raise ct.WinError()

    mapped_view_ptr = MapViewOfFile(mapping_handle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, SHMEMSIZE)

    print("Mapped view addr: 0x{:016X}".format(mapped_view_ptr))
    if not mapped_view_ptr:
        print("Could not map view of file: {:d}".format(GetLastError()))
        CloseHandle(mapping_handle)
        raise ct.WinError()

    byte_len = len(msg) * ct.sizeof(ct.c_wchar)
    print("Message length: {:d} chars ({:d} bytes)".format(len(msg), byte_len))

    memcpy(mapped_view_ptr, msg_ptr, byte_len)  # Comment this line
    RtlCopyMemory(mapped_view_ptr, msg_ptr, byte_len)

    # Python vriant
    shmem = mmap.mmap(0, 256, "MyFileMappingObject_ctypes", mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
    shmem.write(b"Message Python process")

    print("Hit a key to clean all memory maps and exit...")
    msvcrt.getch()

    UnmapViewOfFile(mapped_view_ptr)
    CloseHandle(mapping_handle)

    shmem.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- Added the *argtypes* and *restype* for the functions. Details can be seen in the "*Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)*" and "*Return types*" sections, and of course [MS.Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us) for function declarations. This is ***Undefined Behavior*** (*UB*) especially on *64bit*: [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)
- *memcpy*'s 2<sup>nd</sup> argument is a ***Python*** string, which is **not** the same its *char ** address (not to mention that in *Python 3*, strings are *wchar_t* based) that *memcpy* expects, this will probably also yield *UB*
- Constants:

  - *FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS*'s value is *0x000F001F* (printed out the value from *VStudio 2015*), *0x04* corresponds to *FILE_MAP_READ*
  - Error converting *INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE*'s old value to *HANDLE*, changed it to -1 (as in *handleapi.h*)
- You're calling *CreateFileMappingA* with a *c_wchar_p*. That will set a name consisting of only the 1<sup>st</sup> character from the supplied string for the mapping object because each *wchar_t* consists of 2 bytes: *0x00* plus the corresponding *char* value - '**A**' will be represented as *0x00 0x41* (generally this is **not** true - especially the *0x00* part, but in our case, it is) - so the 2<sup>nd</sup> *char* in the *lpName* argument (due to *little-endianness*) will be *0x00* (*NUL*)
- According to the page above:

  > Accessing the standard C library through `cdll.msvcrt` will use an outdated version of the library that may be incompatible with the one being used by Python.

  So, I also added [[MS.Docs]: RtlCopyMemory function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlcopymemory) to replace *memcpy* (you can comment out its line, I left it there just to show that it works), as in the example ([[MS.Docs]: Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-named-shared-memory)) that you took the code from, and tried to convert it ([*minwinbase.h*: *#36*]: `#define CopyMemory RtlCopyMemory`)
- Changed naming convention to be *Python* compliant ([[Python]: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008))
- Other (non critical) changes (output formatting, moving lines of code around for a better structure, and so on ...)

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048788549]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Mapping object handle: 0x000000000000022C
> Mapped view addr: 0x00000192912B0000
> Message length: 35 chars (70 bytes)
> Hit a key to clean all memory maps and exit...
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: This question is based on the original C implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory Note, that the final `getch_func()` should be **before** closing the memory mapped files, otherwise the reader part won't work!