# Advice dealing with Undefined Behavior in Python using Ctypes - OSError:exception:access violation reading 0x00000000000000000

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, dllimport, hardware-interface

I am using Python 3.8.8 (64-bit) to interface with a device (Meadowlark Spatial Light modulator) using ctypes 1.1.0 to read the provided DLL file and send data to the device. I am using Windows 11 Pro for Workstations.

I am seeing Undefined Behavior where sometimes everything works, sometimes it hangs, and sometimes I receive OSError:exception:access violation reading 0x00000000000000000. I am thinking it must be an error in how I am using ctypes in Python. I have tried different ways to load the DLL file (i.e., WinDLL vs CDLL). I have also gone and added the argtypes and restyle to make sure I am sending the correct types to each function based on [PYTHON - Ctypes : OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xFFFFFFFFFA1C001B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788549/python-ctypes-oserror-exception-access-violation-writing-0xfffffffffa1c001). The error always occurs for slm_lib.Write_image() -- see code below. Clearly, I am missing something, any advice on how to track the source of the error down would be great.

I have also attached the corresponding header file for reference.

```
import numpy
import ctypes as ct
from scipy import misc
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi


#Load the DLL
#Blink_C_wrapper.dll, Blink_SDK.dll, ImageGen.dll, FreeImage.dll and wdapi1021.dll
#should all be located in the same directory as the program referencing the
#library
ct.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Meadowlark Optics\\Blink OverDrive Plus\\SDK\\Blink_C_wrapper")
slm_lib = ct.WinDLL("Blink_C_wrapper")
try:
    slm_lib.Delete_SDK()
    sleep(1)
except:
    pass
slm_lib = ct.WinDLL("Blink_C_wrapper")


# Basic parameters for calling Create_SDK
bit_depth = ct.c_uint(12)
num_boards_found = ct.c_uint(0)
constructed_okay = ct.c_int(0)
is_nematic_type  = ct.c_int(1)
RAM_write_enable = ct.c_int(1)
use_GPU = ct.c_int(1)
max_transients = ct.c_int(10)
board_number = ct.c_int(1)
wait_For_Trigger = ct.c_int(0)
output_Pulse = ct.c_int(0)
timeout_ms = ct.c_uint(5000)
center_x = ct.c_float(1152)
center_y = ct.c_float(1920)

# Call the Create_SDK constructor
# Returns a handle that's passed to subsequent SDK calls
slm_lib.Create_SDK.argtypes=[ct.c_uint, ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint),ct.POINTER(ct.c_int), ct.c_int, ct.c_int,  ct.c_int, ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p]
slm_lib.Create_SDK.restyle=ct.c_int
slm_lib.Create_SDK(bit_depth,ct.byref(num_boards_found), 
                    ct.byref(constructed_okay), is_nematic_type, 
                    RAM_write_enable, use_GPU, max_transients, None)# "SLM_lut.txt")

slm_lib.Write_image.argtypes=[ct.c_int,ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte),ct.c_uint, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, ct.c_uint ]
slm_lib.Write_image.restyle=ct.c_int

slm_lib.ImageWriteComplete.argtypes=[ct.c_int, ct.c_uint]#(board_number, timeout_ms);
slm_lib.ImageWriteComplete.restyle=ct.c_int

if constructed_okay == -1:
    print ("Blink SDK was not successfully constructed");
    # Python ctypes assumes the return value is always int
    # We need to tell it the return type by setting restype
    slm_lib.Get_last_error_message.restype = ct.c_char_p
    print (slm_lib.Get_last_error_message());

    # Always call Delete_SDK before exiting
    slm_lib.Delete_SDK()
else:
    # try:
    print ("Blink SDK was successfully constructed");
    print ("Found %s SLM controller(s)" % num_boards_found.value);
    
    height = ct.c_uint(slm_lib.Get_image_height(board_number));
    width = ct.c_uint(slm_lib.Get_image_width(board_number));
    ImageOne = numpy.empty([width.value*height.value], numpy.uint8, 'C');
    ImageOne*=0
    center_x =  ct.c_uint(width.value//2);
    center_y =  ct.c_uint(height.value//2);
    
    slm_lib.Write_image(board_number, ImageOne.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)), ct.c_uint(height.value*width.value), wait_For_Trigger, output_Pulse, timeout_ms)
    slm_lib.ImageWriteComplete(board_number, timeout_ms);
```

The corresponding header file for Blink_C_wrapper

```
//
//:  Blink_SDK_C_wrapper for programming languages that can interface with DLLs
//
//   (c) Copyright Meadowlark Optics 2017, All Rights Reserved.


#ifndef BLINK_C_WRAPPER_H_
#define BLINK_C_WRAPPER_

#ifdef BLINK_C_WRAPPER_EXPORTS
#define BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { /* using a C++ compiler */
#endif

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API void Create_SDK(unsigned int SLM_bit_depth,
                                      unsigned int* n_boards_found,
                                      int *constructed_ok,
                                      int is_nematic_type,
                                      int RAM_write_enable,
                                      int use_GPU_if_available,
                                      int max_transient_frames,
                                      char* static_regional_lut_file);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API void Delete_SDK();

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Is_slm_transient_constructed();

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Write_overdrive_image(int board,
                            unsigned char* target_phase,
                            int wait_for_trigger,
                            int external_pulse,
                            unsigned int trigger_timeout_ms);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Calculate_transient_frames(unsigned char* target_phase,
                                 unsigned int* byte_count);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Retrieve_transient_frames(unsigned char* frame_buffer);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Write_transient_frames(int board,
                             unsigned char* frame_buffer,
                             int wait_for_trigger,
                             int external_puls,
                             unsigned int trigger_timeout_ms);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Read_transient_buffer_size(char *filename,
                                 unsigned int* byte_count);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Read_transient_buffer(char *filename,
                            unsigned int byte_count,
                            unsigned char *frame_buffer);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Save_transient_frames(char *filename,
                            unsigned char *frame_buffer);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  const char* Get_last_error_message();

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Load_overdrive_LUT_file(char* static_regional_lut_file);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Load_linear_LUT(int board);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  const char* Get_version_info();

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  void SLM_power(int power_state);

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Write_image
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API
  int Write_image(int board,
                  unsigned char* image,
                  unsigned int image_size,
                  int wait_for_trigger,
                  int external_pulse,
                  unsigned int trigger_timeout_ms);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int ImageWriteComplete(int board, unsigned int trigger_timeout_ms);

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Load_LUT_file
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int Load_LUT_file(int board, char* LUT_file);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int Load_LUT_Arrays(int board, const unsigned short* RampUp, const unsigned short* RampDown, const unsigned short* PreRampUp, const unsigned short* PreRampDown, const unsigned short* PostRampUp, const unsigned short* PostRampDown);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int SetRampDelay(int board, unsigned int ramp_delay);

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Compute_TF
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int Compute_TF(float frame_rate);

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Set_true_frames
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API void Set_true_frames(int true_frames);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API void Stop_sequence();

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API double Read_SLM_temperature(int board);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int Get_image_width(int board);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API int Get_image_height(int board);

  BLINK_C_WRAPPER_API double Get_pixel_pitch(int board);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //BLINK_C_WRAPPER_
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you replace all occurrences of `restyle` with `restype`? Also, `Create_SDK` returns `void`, so the `restype` should be `None`, not `c_int`: does that help either?

Comment: Technically CDLL is correct (WinDLL is for `__stdcall` functions) but on 64-bit there is no difference. I don't see anything obviously wrong other than need to use `restype` not `restyle`, but `c_int` is the default anyway if you don't specify it correctly.  Since the error is a null pointer access, is it legal to pass `None` (C `NULL`) for `static_regional_lut_file` of `Create_SDK`?

Comment: @MarkTolonen and Luke Woodward, thank you both for you comments. I have changed by restyles to restype as well as added None for Create_SDK. I swapped back to CDLL. And finally, I now pass a char_p pointing to a file for the static_regional_lut_file. Unfortunately, the error still persists.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose when we can't run the code to reproduce the failure.  Do you have a reliable version of C-only code that calls this API?  We might be able to spot a difference between working C code and non-working Python code.  Note you don't need to wrap every variable in a `ctype`; only variables that are pased `byref` so there is storage for the output.  The wrapped functions with proper `.argtypes` will know how to marshal the Python types otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I only have an .exe file that needs the hardware to run but don't have the actual source code for that. I also have some very incomplete documentation from the company with no helpful responses to my inquiries, hence why I thought I would give stack exchange a try in case it was something obvious. I will keep trying and if the solution is useful will post it to this question.